# Error while trying to build uwp project in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have just updated to vs2019 community to version 16.4.5. Now I am facing one viral issue that whenever i change in class files or xaml and trying to build it is giving error  CopyWin32Resources failed with exit code 500.
In order to fix this, I have to remove vs file bin and obj then restart vs2019 then works.
Anyone has a better solution for this.Kindly share,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to update the windows machine by using Windows Update Assistant. Updating from the update from within windows was not worked for me. Then update to the latest Build tools.[Vs2019 Build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release)